# Angular: How to use different component after build?

Tags: angular

I had build three components in Angular app. I exported that using command

```
ng build --prod
```

I embedded that in my HTML page of a website and

How to display, component number 2 on page 2. And component 3 on page 3?

As I had embedded `<app-root></app-root>` , it displays default component number 1 on all page.

My website is made in PHP and it has few pages.

Comment: *I exported that using command ng build --prod* You exported nothing, you transpiled and assembled application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is meant to be used to build your client-side application. You build all of your pages within the Angular application.

Use a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to define where on a page you wish to display each component. Then, as the user navigates to each component it will be displayed where you defined the router-outlet.

I would *highly* suggest that you work through the Angular tutorial to better understand the structure of an Angular application and how to build one to match your requirements.

You can find the documentation for the tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: I got your point, in AngularJS, we create various controllers and no routing required. We can use components anywhere we want. And I was implementing similar thing. Its just that, I want to see how flexible Angular is. Thanks